# Is it possible to use PIP (picture in picture) in flutter video_player android?

Tags: flutter, video-player, android-video-player, flutter-video-player

I am trying to use pip mode in my flutter app..
for instance thanks to [thanhit93](https://github.com/thanhit93) I found [this](https://github.com/thanhit93/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player/video_player).
but it found that he has customized the package for ios only...
What about android? is it enabled in the default video_player package?

..thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the [easy_pip](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_pip) package. It mirrors the YouTube UI so you would display the video player in the PIP widget.

Comment: It looks great but what I want is to keep pip even when the app is paused, like this one:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19393678/113262274-a30dc500-92fa-11eb-9393-b9793298b90e.gif